# Confidence interval over a normal distribution plot

Tags: r

I want to plot vertical lines on the x position for the confidence interval. I did the statistics, but I cannot find a way to add it to the plot. Please follow this MWE:

```
xseq<-seq(-4,4,.01)
densities<-dnorm(xseq, 0,1)
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar=c(3,4,4,2))
plot(xseq, densities, col="darkgreen",xlab="", ylab="Densidade", type="l",lwd=2, cex=2, main="Normal", cex.axis=.8)
```

Generates:
[image]

The ci is:

```
x<-t.test(xseq, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int
```

But when I try to plot the line with:

```
line(x[1], x[2])
```

It gives me the error:

```
Error in structure(.Call(C_tukeyline, as.double(xy$x[ok]), as.double(xy$y[ok]),  : 
  insufficient observations
```

**After comments pointing out abline()** it works:

[image]

I am, however, incorrect to think that t.test will give cis for a normal distribution.

- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but isnt'it `abline(v=c(x[1],x[2]))`?

Comment: You probably want to use `?abline`. Also your t.test is probably not what you expect.

Comment: That is true, t.test is not the proper function to find the ci in this case. What would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = xseq, y = densities)) +
 geom_point() + 
 geom_vline(xintercept = c(x[1], x[2]))
```

[image]

With proper confidence intervals:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = xseq, y = densities)) +
 geom_point() + 
 geom_vline(xintercept = c(x2[1], x2[2]))
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(xseq = seq(-4,4,.01),
densities = dnorm(xseq, 0,1))

x <- t.test(xseq, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int
x2 <- qnorm(c(0.05, 0.95), mean = mean(xseq), sd = sd(xseq))
```

Comment: x <- t.test(xseq, conf.level = 0.95)$conf.int